Issue with Installing Software in Eclipse IDE via HTTP URL Redirecting to HTTPS
I am trying to install software in Eclipse IDE using the "Install New Software" feature. I have an update site with the following URL:
http://abc.go.net:8000/tool

This URL works fine when accessed via a web browser with http://. However, when I try to use it in Eclipse's "Install New Software" dialog, Eclipse is redirecting to an https:// version of the URL, which causes the installation to fail.
The error message I see in Eclipse is:
Unable to read repository at https://abc.go.net:8000/tool. 

I have confirmed that the https:// version of the URL does not work in the browser, and I'm unsure why Eclipse is attempting to use it.
What I've Tried:

I have verified that the http:// URL works fine in the web browser.
I have tried using http://abc.go.net:8000/tool directly in Eclipse, but it still redirects to https://.
I've checked the settings in Eclipse and tried to disable any forced HTTPS redirects, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Can anyone suggest a way to prevent Eclipse from redirecting to https:// and allow me to install from the http:// URL? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

In the preferences Install/Update > Trust, in the tab Authorities at the bottom, there is a drop-down for http which is by default set to Redirect. Does it work with setting it to Allow (be aware that this is less secure)? See also https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-p2-trust-authority.htm
